# how extract icon pixmap data from icon handle

Tags: python, sendmessage, win32gui

I need to extract taskbar icons from a running application.
So far reading text data from the statusbar is working, however, I have no idea how to extract icon data from a handle that is returned by `sb_retcode = win32api.SendMessage(handle, SB_GETTEXTLENGTH, item, 0)`.

Here is my example code:

```
MAX_LEN = 4096

def get_process_handle(dwProcessId, dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle=False):
    handle = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, dwProcessId)
    if handle is None or handle == 0:
        raise Exception('Error: %s' % GetLastError())
    return handle

def allocate(hProcess, lpAddress, dwSize, flAllocationType, flProtect):
    lpBuffer = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, lpAddress, dwSize, flAllocationType, flProtect)
    if lpBuffer is None or lpBuffer == 0:
        raise Exception('Error: %s' % GetLastError())
    return lpBuffer

# -- get pid for valid window handle
_, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow) 
handle = get_process_handle(pid, win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False)

p_buffer = allocate(handle, 0, MAX_LEN, win32con.MEM_RESERVE | win32con.MEM_COMMIT, win32con.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)

item = 2  # valid item no

sb_retcode = win32api.SendMessage(hWindow, SB_GETTEXTLENGTH, item, 0) 
sb_length = sb_retcode & 0xFFFF 
sb_type = (sb_retcode >> 16) & 0xFFFF

if sb_type == 0 and sb_length > 0:
        # text data
        bufferSize = sb_retcode
        buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(bufferSize)
        bytesRead = c_ulong(0)

        win32api.SendMessage(hWindow, SB_GETTEXT, i, p_buffer)
        if ReadProcessMemory(handle, p_buffer, buffer, bufferSize, bytesRead):
            print('-> ', buffer.value)
        else:
            ErrorNum = win32api.GetLastError()
            print("Error Read Memory: ", ErrorNum, win32api.FormatError(ErrorNum))

    elif sb_type == SBT_OWNERDRAW:
        # icon data
        # sb_retcode should be handle to the icon
        print('-> handle for icon', sb_retcode)

        # ?? how to get bitmap data from icon handle ??
```

`SendMessage` does return a valid handle to the icon, but how do I convert this into a bitmap?